# Can any VIM plugin help me refactor a React component?

Tags: reactjs, vim

I've  been using Vim quite happily and productively for about 15 years. For a while now I mostly program in Ruby/Rails and Javascript projects.

I've occasionally tried IDEs and found that they offer me little that Vim doesn't do better for my needs. Recently however, I've been more and more dissatisfied with a couple of things with Vim as my editor, and most of that has to do with refactoring.

Refactoring that spans multiple files has always been inefficient for me in Vim, and now that I'm working on React apps every day along with Rails code I feel like I'm wasting a LOT of time during refactoring.

Here are some examples of repetitive tasks I find myself spending "too much" time doing:

A simple component name change I need to:

1. change the file name
2. change all import statements
3. change occurrences of the component.

When adding a component to a file:

1. remember to add import statments

When removing a line that refers to a component:

1. remember to remove import statements.

If I want to change the location of one of my components:

1. change all import statements to match.

All of this is quite tedious and I imagine other editors out there have tools to make it less so. What are other Vim / React devs out there doing to make their lives easier with respect to this boilerplate and repetitive tasks. Some kind of linter?

For example, instead of the build failing because I didn't import the file, I'd rather the import statement just be added for me (if unambiguous), or be given a list of options to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

You’ll want to learn how to use `:cdo`/`:argdo`, `:substitute`, and macros properly (especially dealing with complex renamings like this). `:global` will also be useful. In general, the most efficient large refactorings are done with `:` commands and the occasional normal-mode, or entirely with macros.

Renaming the file is a simple `mv` in terminal land, or `:Rename` if you have tpope’s eunuch plugin.

ALE can help lint open files in vim, though you might be happier with a whole project lint and the quickfix list. Learning how to set the quickfix list with your errors (`:make` and `-q` are my top two) is a huge boon.

Comment: I started to explore quickfix, but I'm not sure it will do what I'm after. I'm looking for some tooling that will, for example add missing import statements, and remove unnecessary ones...